# Java Arrays: Finding Unique Numbers In A Group of 10 Inputted Numbers

Tags: java, arrays

I'm at a loss here.

I have this homework assignment where I have to enable the user to input 10 numbers, place them in an array, and figure out which inputted numbers are unique.

This is my workflow right now: Input number> If number has not been inputted before, store in array; if number has been inputted before, ignore> Display the numbers inputted> Display the unique numbers

ex: Inputting 1 2 3 5 1 2 4 6 would find the unique numbers and show "1 2 3 4 5 6"

So far my code looks like this:

```
public class HwChapter6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

        int[] count = new int[10];
        int number = 0;
        int x = 0;
        boolean unique = false;
        int length = count.length;
        System.out.println("Insert 10 single digit numbers in any order your heart desires:");
        for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
            count[i] = input.nextInt();
            number = count[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < count.length; j++) {
```

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: You're violating this part your plan: "* If number has not been inputted before, store in array;*".  You store in array whatever comes from a user.

Comment: What you have to do is to check before storing in the array.. if(theValue isn't in the array)then here i add value to the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the numbers at they are entered, then keep track of which ones are unique by marking the same positions in a second (boolean) array with `true` if they are unique and `false` otherwise.

Then, when you print out the unique values, only print the value from each position in `numbers[]` if that position in `uniques[]` contains `true`.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] numbers = new int[10];
boolean[] uniques = new boolean[10];

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a value: \n" + "[" + (i + 1) + "]: ");
    numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
    uniques[i] = true;
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        if(numbers[i] == numbers[j] && i != j) {
            uniques[i] = false;
        }
    }
}

System.out.println("\nThe numbers you entered were: \n");
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println(numbers[i] + ", ");
}
System.out.println("done.\n\n");

System.out.println("\nThe uniqe numbers you entered were: \n");
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if(uniques[i]) {
        System.out.println(numbers[i] + ", ");
    }
}
System.out.println("done.\n\n");
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of an array of input values, put them in a `Set` of `Integers`. Sets, by definition, store only unique values. If you add 3 'foos', there will be only one 'foo' in the set.

```
// Add this to your top-level loop
Set<Integer> uniqueValues = new TreeSet<Integer>;
uniqueValues.add(number);

// Add this after the loop to write all unique values on one line
for (Integer value : uniqueValues) {
  System.out.print(value.toString() + " ");
}

// Now end the line.
System.out.println();
```

Comment: I'm not sure OP is allowed to use `Collection` as they probably did not cover it in the course yet.

Comment: This is probably a much more efficient way to accomplish this assignment, but I'm restricted to using arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Store all numbers in an array.
For each stored number: check if number was inserted before and save that in a boolean array.
Print all numbers that are not marked in the boolean array.

```
java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

int[] numbers = new int[10];
boolean[] usedBefore = new boolean[10];

// Insert all numbers
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    // Read number from console
    numbers[i] = input.nextInt();

    // Check if number was inserted before
    usedBefore[i] = false;
    for(int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
        if(numbers[k] == numbers[i]) {
            usedBefore[i] = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

// Print all numbers that were not inserted before
for(int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
    if(!usedBefore[i]) {
        System.out.print(String.valueOf(numbers[j])+" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: That sort of gets the job done but it's still remembering multiples instances of the same value. It's also printing out the array in
every line. 

I've gone to using 2 for loops and a while that look like this:

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
for (int j = 0; j < unique.length; j++) {
if (unique[j] == numbers[i]) {
uniqueCheck = true;
break;
}                   
while (k == numbers.length && m < 10) {           
System.out.println("Inputted numbers were:" + numbers[i]);
System.out.println("Unique numbers were:" + unique[j]);
i++;
j++;
m++;
Still a no go

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and most concise and efficient way is to destructively parse the array for uniques using its first number as a magic value, after all other operations on it are complete:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int magic = 0;
int[] numbers = new int[10];

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a value: \n" + "[" + (i + 1) + "]: ");
    numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
}

System.out.println("\nThe numbers you entered were: \n");
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println(numbers[i] + ", ");
}
System.out.println("done.\n\n");

System.out.println("The unique numbers are: ");
magic = numbers[0];
System.out.println(magic + ", ");
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        if(numbers[i] == numbers[j] && j != i) {
            numbers[j] = magic;
        }
    }
    if(numbers[i] != magic) {
        System.out.println(numbers[i] + ", ");
    }
}
System.out.println("done.\n\n");
```

Yes, I have two answers - this one is significantly different from the other one, and is better, though it is much more difficult for beginners to understand. Both solutions are valid, however.