# Java Arrays: Finding Unique Numbers In A Group of 10 Inputted Numbers RE:

Tags: java, arrays, int

[Java Arrays: Finding Unique Numbers In A Group of 10 Inputted Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885162/java-arrays-finding-unique-numbers-in-a-group-of-10-inputted-numbers)

I have a problem that I have looked into Doestovsky's question but from his question, I need to know on how to make the part on finding duplicates into a function of it's own:

```
java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

int[] numbers = new int[10];
boolean[] usedBefore = new boolean[10];

// Insert all numbers
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    // Read number from console
    numbers[i] = input.nextInt();

    // Check if number was inserted before
    usedBefore[i] = false;
    for(int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
        if(numbers[k] == numbers[i]) {
            usedBefore[i] = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

// Print all numbers that were not inserted before
for(int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
    if(!usedBefore[i]) {
        System.out.print(String.valueOf(numbers[j])+" ");
    }
}
```

I have tried this part of this code and it worked but I need this to take the part that find duplicates into a function of it's own that is powered by arrays.

Credits to ThimoKl for creating this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try something else, using Treeset, and let's get rid of that for for

```
import java.util.*;

public class duplicate {

   private static TreeSet<Integer> numbers = new TreeSet<Integer>();
   private static TreeSet<Integer> duplicates = new TreeSet<Integer>();

   public static void main (String[] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      int n=0;
      int numberOfIntToRead=10;

      for (int i = 0; i < numberOfIntToRead; i++) {
          // Read number from console
          n=input.nextInt();
          // Check if number was inserted before
          checkIfDuplicate(n);
      }

      // Print all numbers that were not inserted more than one time
      for (Integer j : numbers) {
          System.out.print(j+" ");
      }
   }


   public static void checkIfDuplicate(int n){
      if(!numbers.contains(n) && !duplicates.contains(n)){
         numbers.add(n);
      }else{
         numbers.remove(n);
         duplicates.add(n);
      }
   }

}
```

But if you really want to use arrays an not a Collection of any sort, then you need to declare your arrays as class members, that way you can put the "for" that checks for duplicates in a function a give it your i, and this way you can also put the "for" that does the printing in a function. and give to it numbers.length. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a Set to make finding duplicates easy:

```
List<Integer> dups = new ArrayList<>();
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
for (int i : numbers)
    if (!set.add(i))
        dups.add(i);
```

This works because `Set#add()` returns `false` if it doesn't change as a result if being called, which happens eggnog the set *already* contains the number - ie it's a dup.